# Fade content on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, pageload

I have one page style site. My menu:

```
<ul id="creamenu" class="menuHolder">
  <li><a id="menu1" href="#/1">1</a></li>
  <li><a id="menu2" href="#/2">2</a></li>
  <li><a id="menu3" href="#/3">3</a></li>
  <li><a id="menu4" href="#/4">4</a></li>
  <li><a id="menu5" href="#/5">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

When click menu1, go to content on same page. My content structure:

```
<div id='menu1' class="fancyscroll-section" style="left:10800px;">
<div class="fancyscroll-content row blue">
/* Content items */         
</div>
</div>
```

I want when get content page, contents load via fade effect. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is! It's even called `.fadeIn()`!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [**fadeIn()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) You have same id for first menu item and the div you want to relate with it. You `should have unique ids` for html elements. If element is already visible `hide` it before you call fadeIn.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mxkz/1/)**

```
$('#menu1').click(function() {
    $('#menu1_content').hide().fadeIn(2000);
});​
```